# Using a SUMIFS formula to select the same column in multiple tables in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to shorten my formula a little and having a hard time figuring out the proper method to do so.  I am trying to select certain cells in multiple tables to produce a single total.  My code is this:

```
=SUMIFS(TransactionsChase[INFLOW],TransactionsChase[DATE],">="&Dec,TransactionsChase[DATE],"<"&DecPayChk2,TransactionsChase[CATEGORY],"<>"&"From*")
+SUMIFS(TransactionsPatelcoChecking[INFLOW],TransactionsPatelcoChecking[DATE],">="&Dec,TransactionsPatelcoChecking[DATE],"<"&DecPayChk2,TransactionsPatelcoChecking[CATEGORY],"<>"&"From*")
+SUMIFS(TransactionsPatelcoMM[INFLOW],TransactionsPatelcoMM[DATE],">="&Dec,TransactionsPatelcoMM[DATE],"<"&DecPayChk2,TransactionsPatelcoMM[CATEGORY],"<>"&"From*")                                                
+SUMIFS(TransactionsCash[INFLOW],TransactionsCash[DATE],">="&Dec,TransactionsCash[DATE],"<"&DecPayChk2,TransactionsCash[CATEGORY],"<>"&"From*")
```

I would love to simplify it if possible into one sumifs statement.  Any ideas?

Comment: No. Well... yes but you have to include the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) and that negates much iof the efficiency of a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and even that works better when you put the table names on the worksheet. So Yes but IMO it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the four table names within the a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) with a volatile [INDIRECT¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) then wrap the whole thing in a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) and finalize it as an array² formula, the formula can be shortened visually but not calculation-wise.

In the following image, your original formula is in J2. The revised formula is J3 as,

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(N$2:N$5&"[INFLOW]"),
            INDIRECT(N$2:N$5&"[DATE]"), ">="&Dec,
            INDIRECT(N$2:N$5&"[DATE]"), "<"&DecPayChk2,
            INDIRECT(N$2:N$5&"[CATEGORY]"), "<>From*"))
```

Results should similar to the following. Note the minor improvement made to the `, "<>From*"` criteria. The table names could also be written out longhand. Instead of `N$2:N$5` as,

```
{"TransactionsChase", "TransactionsPatelcoChecking", "TransactionsPatelcoMM", "TransactionsCash"}
```

[image: sumifs_multiple_tables]

As you can see from the sample image above, this formula will survive tables of varying row length. The only question that remains would be *'Is it worth it?'*

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>